# Placeholders for LIKE operator in postgresql and python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Not sure how to get rid of type errors without jeopardizing functionality of LIKE operator - namely the % to indicate finding strings in the beginning, end, or throughout.

Trying to search for isbns of books that has the variable characters 380X.

Getting rid of % to fix type error returned an empty list.

```
isbn = request.form.get("search")
# Search the database for matching or part matching string, isbn, title, or author
book = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE '%:isbn%'", {"isbn":str(isbn)}).fetchall()
```

expected: a list of books and their columns but i get this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax
>   error at or near "380" LINE 1: SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE
>   '%'380'%'
>                                                  ^
>
> [SQL: SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE '%%%(isbn)s%%']

Comment: Placeholders don't operate exactly like string interpolation (which is why they're safer from SQL injection attacks). Your best bet is probably to pass in a string including the %. Something like `...LIKE :isbn", {"isbn": '%' + str(isbn) + '%'}).fetchall()`

Comment: Thank you, this one solved it. I didn't know you can pass % into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the % like so: 
`db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn LIKE '%%' || %(isbn)s || '%%', {"isbn":str(isbn)})`

Note that you use %% instead of % when using named parameters, at least in psycopg2.